# Collection property is null. Custom control dependency properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have a custom control which I'm trying to extend the Track class.

```
public class MultiThumbTrack : Track
{tyMetadata(typeof(MultiThumbTrack)));
    }

    public List<Thumb> ThumbsList
    {
        get { return (List<Thumb>)GetValue(ThumbsListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThumbsListProperty, value); }
    }

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,2" Placement="Top" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="4" Margin="0,2,0,0" Placement="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsednd}" Height="4.0" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="center">
                    <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Height="4.0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
                <local:MultiThumbTrack x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                    <local:MultiThumbTrack.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </local:MultiThumbTrack.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <local:MultiThumbTrack.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </local:MultiThumbTrack.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <!--<local:MultiThumbTrack.Thumb>
                        "Center" />
                    </local:MultiThumbTrack.Thumb>-->
                    <local:MultiThumbTrack.ThumbsList>
                        <Thumb Margin="1,15,0,0" x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="13" Width="9" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </local:MultiThumbTrack.ThumbsList>
                </local:MultiThumbTrack>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But it gives me the "Collection property 'CustomCollectionControl.MultiThumbTrack'.'ThumbsList' is null." error when I try to do this:

```
<local:MultiThumb
```

Comment: Initialize the ThumbsList property to a `new List<Thumb>()` in the MultiThumbTrack  constructor. Otherwise it's `null`. Probably very soon someone will tell you to set the default value of the dependency property by property metadata. Don't do that, because the same `List<Thumb>` instance would then be used by all control instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize the ThumbsList property in the instance constructor:

```
public class MultiThumbTrack : Track
{
    static MultiThumbTrack()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiThumbTrack), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MultiThumbTrack)));
    }

    public MultiThumbTrack()
    {
        ThumbsList = new List<Thumb>();
    }

    ...
}
```